# How to convert group.iterrows() loop result to dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Consider below data:

```
df['rank']=df.groupby('Contact').cumcount()
df.set_index('rank', inplace=True, drop=True)               
df
```

| Contact | New | Old | DateNew | DateOld | moddate | User | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | mary | False | True | 2021-01-12 11:00:00 | NaT | 2021-01-12 12:48:00 | sys |
| 1 | mary | True | False | NaT | 2021-01-12 11:00:00 | 2021-01-12 12:47:00 | Rob |
| 2 | mary | False | True | 2021-01-12 11:00:00 | NaT | 2021-01-12 12:45:00 | sys |
| 3 | mary | True | False | NaT | 2021-11-29 11:00:00 | 2021-01-12 12:44:00 | Rob |
| 0 | john | True | False | NaT | 2021-12-10 11:00:00 | 2021-12-10 16:15:00 | Tina |
| 1 | john | False | True | 2021-12-10 11:00:00 | NaT | 2021-12-10 15:30:00 | sys |
| 2 | john | True | False | NaT | 2021-12-10 11:00:00 | 2021-12-10 15:29:00 | Rina |
| 3 | john | False | True | 2021-12-10 11:00:00 | NaT | 2021-12-10 12:37:00 | sys |

How do I convert the below result to dataframe? `df` is a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` and `grp` is a `pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy`.

```
grp = df.groupby('Contact')
for name,group in grp:
        for i,row in group.iterrows():
            
            if i < len(group)-1:
                if (group.loc[i,'Old'] == group.loc[i+1,'New']):
                    if group.loc[i,'User'] == 'sys':
                        if group.loc[i+1,'User'] !='sys':
                            group.loc[i,'Overwritten']= True
                            
                        else:
                            group.loc[i,'Overwritten']= False
                    else:
                        group.loc[i,'Overwritten']= False
                              
                else:
                    group.loc[i,'Overwritten']= False
    
        print(group)
```

The above solution may not be the best approach, maybe I can use `shift` function. But I would like to know how I can get the `groupby` results in the loop as data frame so I can proceed with more filtrations/analysis. I am still kind of newbie in Pandas.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure *New* (string names) and *Old* (boolean) are comparable?

Comment: @Parfait Is there a way I can get print(group) result as a dataframe? when I run 'group' in a new line in jupyter, it returns the last block of groupby results as a dataframe with the new column 'overwritten' , I want the whole groupby results as new dataframe. are you able to help? thanks

Comment: Simply initialize a list before loop then append every `group` to list. Then run `pd.concat` on list to stack groups back together.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the need of `groupby` and`iterrows` by sorting by *Contact* and calculating the boolean column, *Overwritten*, using `shift` columns. In fact, you can flatten all `if` to a single logic check:

```py
calc_df = (
    df.sort_values('Contact')           # SORT BY GROUPING VARIABLE
      .reset_index(drop=True)           # RESET INDEX FOR SHIFT COLS
      .assign(                          # ADD SHIFT HELPER COLUMNS
          Contact_ = lambda df: df['Contact'].shift(-1),
          New_ = lambda df: df['New'].shift(-1),
          User_ = lambda df: df['User'].shift(-1),
          Overwritten = lambda df: (    # CALCULATE BOOLEAN COLUMN
               (df['Contact'] == df['Contact_']) &
               (df['Old'] == df['New_']) &
               (df['User'] == 'sys') &
               (df['User_'] != 'sys')
          )
      )
)

calc_df
```

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful, but is there a way I can use loop as above and return the groupby results to /as a dataframe , that would help me in proceeding with further data filterations and analysis.

Comment: This solution avoids looping and actually follows up on your last paragraph with `shift`. Unlike general Python, looping should be avoided in pandas and numpy programming for vectorized operations. When data gets much larger, you would be thankful for such a approach!